# How to count repetition for each value individually in Python

Tags: python, excel, count

This is my first post, and I want to say hello to you all.

I need help counting the codes of certain items that have the same value. For example, if I have the following article codes:
Article01,
Article01,
Article01,
Article02,
Article03,
Article03.

It should look like this:
Article01_1,
Article01_2,
Article01_3,
Article02_1,
Article03_1,
Article03_2.

The data source is excel, and I already created the code pairing, but I can't figure out how to count each code individually.

Current code:

```
for row in range(rbegin, rfinish):
    for col in range(1, 2):  
        char = get_column_letter(col)
        article_number = ws[char + str(row)].value
        new_article_number = article_number[:-4] 
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(articles_path): 
            for folder_article in files:  
                if folder_article.__contains__(new_article_number):
                    article_found_count += 1
                    article_copy = os.path.join(subdir, folder_article)  
                    shutil.copy2(article_copy, paired_articles_path)  
                    updated_article = folder_article[:10] #because article codes from first column have 10 characters
                    print(f"{new_article_number};{updated_article}_{article_found_count}")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the posted code solves your problem, why are you here?  If it does not, please details how its results differ from what you want, and what you did to try and resolve them.

Comment: Also give a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you don't need to add the code for how you read the data from xl for example if there is no problem in that

Comment: Hi, @ScottHunter. Actually, I posted this so you can see what the pairing code looks like, but I didn't make a counter for each code individually as I mentioned above. Thank you

Comment: I corrected the code, because I think the problem is in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

The [Counter class from collections module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is likely what you are looking for. Example usage:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()

for article in ["A1", "A2", "A2", "A1", "A3", "A1"]:
    c[article] += 1
    print(f"{article}_{c[article]}")
```

Output:

```
A1_1
A2_1
A2_2
A1_2
A3_1
A1_3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe i didn't explain well. There are two columns in the file. In the first column is the code of the article, and in the second column there is also the code of the article that should be counted. According to your code, only the values ​​from the first column (in your case a list) would be counted, but not the matching values.

Comment: You definitely did not explain yourself, you also didn't provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just to let you know that I found a solution. I inserted the second column, that was generated based on the first, into the list, and did what treuss suggested. Thank you treuss.